# How to know what files on Google Drive (sheets, docs, slides) has GAS inside?

Tags: google-drive, google-apps-script, google-drive-search

How to know (search or filter search results) if file on Google Drive (sheet, doc, slide) has GAS inside because Google Apps Scripts are hidden inside files (i.e. custom functions) impossible to search.

Was googling for some scripts (kind a: list files with gas script inside) but unsuccessfully.

My idea is to adapt [script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19538-file-sharing-permissions) but I'm unable to figure out what [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) to use, because I can't find anything related to scripts or content

Answer (score 1):

*[Cross-posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218582/1595451) to SO*

Today, 2018-1-11, Google launched the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/home). It list all the script project files, standalone and bounded.

Reference

- [3 new tools to help improve your Apps Script development and management experience](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2018/01/three-new-tools-to-help-improve-your.html)

Related questions on SO:

- [Can't find Google Apps Script project in docs list in Google Drive, Android or desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11568898/1595451)
- [Listing all container-bound scripts in all my documents and spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24794739/1595451)